# Why do I got io_context do_one() runtime crash?

Tags: boost-asio

This is my signal handler:

```
SignalHandler::SignalHandler(boost::asio::io_context & context) : _context(context), _signals(context, SIGINT, SIGTERM)
{
    _signals.async_wait(std::bind(&SignalHandler::HandleTermSignal, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

When I run this code:

```
SignalHandler signalHandler(io);
std::thread t([&signalHandler]() {
    signalHandler.HandleInput();
});
boost::system::error_code errcode;
try {
    io.run(errcode);
    logger->info(PACK("err:{}"), errcode.message());
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    logger->critical(PACK("Exception Catched : {}, err:{}"),e.what(), errcode.message());
}
t.join();
```

I get this call trace:

```
QuoteSvr.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_context::do_one(unsigned long msec, boost::system::error_code & ec) Ln 420 C++
QuoteSvr.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_context::run(boost::system::error_code & ec) Ln 202 C++
QuoteSvr.exe!boost::asio::io_context::run(boost::system::error_code & ec) Ln72 C++
QuoteSvr.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Ln 170 C++
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not add additional information as comments to your questions, **edit** your question instead. Also be sure to check out the nifty formatting features like `this` for code etc.

Comment: could you post the definition of your type 'SignalHandler'. there is nothing in `io.run()` that could crash your program, as it just execute your completion-handler,  so make sure your completion-handler is not accessing something that is not properly initialised or something that didn't exist.

Comment: "something that didn't exist" meaning something that lost its life-time.